# We are discussing useful things. We are discussing on useful things

Tags: word-usage, differences, prepositions

We are discussing useful things. We are discussing on useful things. 
Which is the correct answer? 
Can we use preposition here?

Comment: *Discuss* admits so readily of transitive usage that the preposition is worse than useless, merely confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb is *to discuss (transitive, used with object)*, which is "to discuss something".

We are discussing useful things - Correct.

We are discussing on useful things - Incorrect. However, you can say, "We're having a discussion **on** (some) useful things."